# How do I find the equation of the normal to $y=2\sin(x/4)$ at $x=\pi$

Tags: calculus

The question is:

> Find the equation of the normal to $y$ at $x = \pi$ when $y = 2\sin(x/4), 0 \leq x \leq 4\pi$.

I can't figure out out to find the normal of the equation.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x)=2 \sin (x/4)$ and let $y=mx+b$ the equation of the normal to$f$ at $x= \pi$.

Then we have:

$b+m \pi =y( \pi) =f( \pi)$

and

$ m= - \frac{1}{f'( \pi)}$.

It is now your turn to determine $m$ and $b$ from these equations.

Answer (score 0):

The equation of a non-vertical line with slope $s,$ passing thru the point $(x_1,y_1),$ is $y-y_1=s(x-x_1).$

Two non-vertical lines at right angles to each other have slopes whose product is $\;-1.$

The slope of the tangent to $y=f(x)$ at the point $(x_1,f(x_1))$ is $f'(x_1).$ So if $f'(x_1)\ne 0$ the slope of the normal to $y=f(x)$ at the point $(x_1,f(x_1)$ is $\;-1/f'(x_1).$

So if $f'(x_1)\ne 0$ the equation of the normal to $y=f(x)$ at $(x_1,f(x_1))$ is $$y-f(x_1)=(-1/f'(x_1))(x-x_1).$$